# Check whether one of several cells is blank

Tags: excel-formula

How to check whether one of several cells is blank?

I know that `ISBLANK(cell)` or `LEN(cell)` can be used to check whether a cell is empty, but I don't know how to apply them to "one of several cells"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `=IF(COUNTA(UNIQUE(ISBLANK(range)))=2, TRUE, FALSE)`

[image]

Another option is something like
`=IF(COUNTA(H2:H4)-ROWS(H2:H4)=0, FALSE, TRUE)`

EDIT: If your range is horizontal, you'll want to use something like `=IF(COUNTA(UNIQUE(ISBLANK(range),1))=2, TRUE, FALSE)` or `=IF(COUNTA(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(ISBLANK(range))))=2, TRUE, FALSE)`

Comment: Thank you! I tried: `=IF(COUNTA(UNIQUE(ISBLANK(E2:J2)))=6, "COMPLETE", "N/A")` to see whether there are empty values within `E2:J2` and it will always return `COMPLETE`. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: @TaihouKai Yes, two things: 1) if your range is horizontal, you'll either want to flip it to vertical with ```TRANSPOSE``` or use the built in functionality with ```UNIQUE``` with ```...UNIQUE(ISBLANK(range),1)``` 2) It doesn't matter the size of your range, you'll always want to use "2" as the criteria for the ```IF```. See edit for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

[Euler's Disgraced Stepchild's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68970817/12427876) works perfectly.

And I also figured out another approach just now so I post it here anyway:

```
=IF(COUNTBLANK(range)=0, "Complete", "Incomplete")
```

Comment: Wow, that is much simpler haha. I think this is the better answer, so would recommend marking this one as accepted